# KonvaJS progressive image loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, html5-canvas, konvajs

Following the KonvaJS Image example here:
[HTML Canvas Image tutorial](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Image.html)

I'm trying to load big sized images (3 - 5 MB). Image loading takes a lot of time and making a very bad experience. IS there is a way to do progressive (or Lazy) loading for the image on Konva Stage (Canvas)?

Development stack include:
`NodeJs`
`react`
[`react-konva`](https://github.com/lavrton/react-konva)

Comment: I think it will be better to show light "loading" image instead of the original image, while it is loading.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it. With canvas 2d you can't, the image needs to be fully loaded and decoded to be drawn on it, and KonvaJS uses canvas 2d.

Try an alternative solution. Compress the image, cut the image in multiple parts so you can draw them as they load, resize down the image, try different formats...

Comment: Well... you could create your own image decoder and that way you could do the progressive display, but that seems quite crazy and I don't think that is what you are asking about